# Dynamically created modal not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, bootstrap-modal

I have a form where next fields and links created using `add more`. The first row displays the modal window perfectly, but the link which is created dynamically does not show the modal. Dynamic rows are created as below :

```
$row += '<tr>';

$row += '<td width="20%">';
$row += '<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="showModal'+sl_no+'"> Add Documents/Req. </a>';
$row += '</td>';

$row += '<div class="modal fade" id="modal'+sl_no+'" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">';
$row += '<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">';
$row += '<div class="modal-content">';
$row += '<div class="modal-header">';
$row += '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>';
$row += '<h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>';
$row += '</div>';
$row += '<div class="modal-body">';
$row += '<p>One fine body&hellip;</p>';
$row += '</div>';
$row += '<div class="modal-footer">';
$row += '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>';
$row += '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>';
$row += '</div>';
$row += '</div>';
$row += '</div>';
$row += '</div>';
```

And this is placed :

```
$last_tr = $('#indent_item_list tr:last');
$last_tr.after($new_row);

$('#showModal'+sl_no).on('click', function() { alert('fff');
  $('#modal'+sl_no).modal('show');
});
```

but when I click `Add Documents/Req` its not showing the modal ! How to solve this ?

[FIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/rntshg76/)

Comment: Your fiddle is a bit wrong, `item` is not defined

Comment: @VergilPenkov thank you for pointing out ! Updated

Comment: try this https://jsfiddle.net/64n9mmfj/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of issues in your code:

1) You are trying to append div inside table element. Which is not going to work. You need to append the div element either in td or have a separate container for modal.

2) Also you don't need to attach click event on each row after appending it. You need to use static parent element for event delegation. Which is table element in current case. Along with is start with attribute to target all row element starting with id `showModal`:

```
$('#indent_item_list').on('click','[id^=showModal]', function() {
  $('#modal'+this.id.replace('showModal','')).modal('show');
});
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9mbk7u79/)**

Answer (score 1):

Adding a div element in tr is not a good practice

You can do something like this

https://jsfiddle.net/rntshg76/4/

HTML :-

```
<div class="modals-container">
    <div class="modal fade" id="modal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
</div>

<table class="table" id="indent_item_list">
<tr>
    <th>LINK</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="showModal1"> Add Documents/Req. </a> 
    </td>

</tr>
</table>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-warning add_more_item btn-sm">Add More Item
```

Javascript

```
var sl_no = 1;
$('#showModal1').click(function() {
    $('#modal1').modal('show');  
});

$('.add_more_item').click(function(e) {

    sl_no++;
    $new_row = generateARow(sl_no);
    $last_tr = $('#indent_item_list tr:last');

    //$(".select2").select2("destroy");
    $last_tr.after($new_row);

    $('#showModal'+sl_no).on('click', function() {
        $('#modal'+sl_no).modal('show');
    });

    item++;
});

function generateARow(sl_no) {
$row = '';
$modal = '';
$row += '<tr>';

$row += '<td width="20%">';
$row += '<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="showModal'+sl_no+'"> Add Documents/Req. </a>';
$row += '</td>';

$row += '</tr>';



$modal += '<div class="modal fade" id="modal'+sl_no+'" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">';
$modal += '<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">';
$modal += '<div class="modal-content">';
$modal += '<div class="modal-header">';
$modal += '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>';
$modal += '<h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>';
$modal += '</div>';
$modal += '<div class="modal-body">';
$modal += '<p>One fine body&hellip;</p>';
$modal += '</div>';
$modal += '<div class="modal-footer">';
$modal += '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>';
$modal += '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>';
$modal += '</div>';
$modal += '</div>';
$modal += '</div>';
$modal += '</div>';
$(".modals-container").append($modal);
    return $row;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Code is fine.
The problem you are having is that your modal is beeing added to a table. Which does won't work with bootstrap.

Check if you are maybe able to put the modal outside the table and everything should work just fine.

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

replace in your fiddle code

```
$('#showModal1').click(function() {
```

to new code

```
$(document).on('click', '[id^=showModal]', function() {
```